# sum up results of awk and grep

Tags: awk, grep

I have put together a little chain of `grep` and `awk` commands that return me a column of floating point numbers and I would like to know their **sum**, so something like:

```
cat file | grep 'money' | awk '{print $3}' | grep -v 'nonsense'
1.23
4.56
7.8
cat file | grep 'money' | awk '{print $3}' | grep -v 'nonsense' | sum
13.68
```

Does anybody know a way to do that ?

---

Edit:
The example given is just a simplification of my actual command, so my question is not a duplicate of the link provided, since the solution given there is not really applicable to my problem. Also the title of the question does not describe the problem I have, therefore I couldn't find it. RavinderSingh13's answer is nice, precise and simple enough to be adaptable to my problem. Thanks again.

Comment: Note that given duplicate link is **not** a good reference answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Following `awk` may help you on same:

```
awk '/money/{sum+=$3} END{print sum}' Input_file
```